# How to identify a QGraphicsItem?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qgraphicsitem

I want to know if there's a way of getting a QGraphicsItem's id. Nothing complicated. Lets say I have a QGraphicsScene and I created a lot of rectangles of the same size and color in it. Even if not with ids, than how can I identify them?

UPDATE
Here's some of my code

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_path, self)
        self.variables()
        
        self.ui.create_button.clicked.connect(self.creator)
        self.scene.focusItemChanged.connect(self.nameDisplay)
        
    def variables(self):        
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.ui.canvas_area.setScene(self.scene)
        
         
    def creator(self):
        rect = self.scene.addRect(-20,-20,40,40, QPen(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.gray))
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        
    def nameDisplay(self, newFocusItem, oldFocusItem, reason):
        self.ui.name_line.setText(str(self.scene.focusItem()))       
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_window = Test()
    test_window.ui.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When/how do you need to "identify" those items? Are those items added dynamically?

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your fast reply! I provided some of my code so you'll have clearer picture of what's going on. If you'll run the code you'll see a push button and when you click at it QGraphicsItem will be created. I want to connect those QGraphicsItems to some functions. So, when I select one of them something will happen( doesn't matter what). In case of QPushButtons we would simply do myPushButton.clicked.connect(myFunction). Can I do something similar with QGraphicsItems?

Comment: Note: one of the biggest limitations of `QUiLoader` is that it cannot "install" an UI on an existing widget (PyQt allows that instead, through `uic.loadUi`). Extreme care should be taken when creating QMainWindow and QDialog: if you use QUiLoader, you should not create a main window or dialog in Designer, as you would be actually reparenting them to the widget instance you're using (which might also create serious issues); you should always use a basic form (QWidget) instead and, most importantly, add it to a main layout set for the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGraphicsItem is not a QObject, so it doesn't support the property system, but it has limited support for storing properties through [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setData).

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    count = 0
    # ...

    def creator(self):
        rect = self.scene.addRect(-20,-20,40,40, QPen(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.gray))
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        rect.setData(0, self.count)
        self.count += 1

    def nameDisplay(self, newFocusItem, oldFocusItem, reason):
        if newFocusItem and newFocusItem.data(0) is not None:
            self.ui.name_line.setText('Item {}'.format(newFocusItem.data(0)))
```

Note: the `key` argument of `setData()` and `data()` must be an integer, and there's no way to know if (and which) keys are set: you can only check if the key value is not `None`. If you need more complex data mapping, you can use a dictionary as value, or just subclass (see below).

It's important to consider that while one might try to set an attribute for the item returned by `addRect()`, it wouldn't work: we should remember that PyQt is a binding to Qt, and all python objects used for Qt objects are *wrappers*.

Consider the following:

```
    def creator(self):
        # ...
        rect.id = self.count

    def nameDisplay(self, newFocusItem, oldFocusItem, reason):
        print(hasattr(newFocusItem, 'id')
```

This will always print `False`, and that's because we only created an attribute for the wrapper reference in `creator`, but since that reference is just local and the attribute is set on *that* reference (not the wrapped object), it will be garbage collected and the attribute will be lost.

A possible option would be to add a persistent reference for each item:

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.items = []

    def creator(self):
        # ...
        rect.id = self.count
        self.items.append(rect)
```

But I'd suggest to stick with the `setData()` option, as it is more compliant with how Qt works.

Alternatively, we can create a custom QGraphicsRectItem subclass and add it with `self.scene.addItem()`. In that case, the python wrapper will be persistent and the attribute will be preserved:

```
class MyRect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, w, h, pen, brush):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.id = id
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.setBrush(brush)

class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    # ...
    def creator(self):
        rect = MyRect(self.count, -20, -20, 40, 40, QPen(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.gray))
        self.scene.addItem(rect)
        # ...

    def nameDisplay(self, newFocusItem, oldFocusItem, reason):
        if hasattr(newFocusItem, 'id'):
            self.name_line.setText('Item {}'.format(newFocusItem.id))
```

Comment: sorry for my late reply.  I tried all the methods you suggested and I think I'm going to keep up with the last one. This is some good explanation and it helped me a lot ,so thank you!

Comment: Hi!
Sorry for disturbing you again. I got kind of messed up. Could you please tell me how can I select any of those QGraphicsItems by those names that we apply on them(  item1, item2 etc.)? Or it wasn't possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? In any case, you can access all items using [`items()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#items), so just loop over them and check if `hasattr(item, 'id')` returns `True` (or `isinstance(item, MyRect)`), or use the list like in the third example; then just verify that the id matches the one you need. Alternatively, use a dictionary, but you *must* be sure that all items have unique ids.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! When I try this out I'll let you know.